# How can I force apache to redirect www SSL request to non-www SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I know there are plenty of articles here talking about almost equal questions. However I couldn't fix it yet.

We have a normal wordpress domain

domain.com

I have two virtual hosts, one to http and another to https, from http virtual host I make a redirect to force the https always

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      domain.com
        ServerAlias     www.domain.com
        Redirect permanent / https://domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

then my https virtualhost is something like

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName     domain.com
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/vhosts/puntdona.com/httpdocs
....
</VirtualHost>
```

**Problem:**

every time I enter into navigator something like

https://www.domain.com

navigator (Google,etc) complains about it because the certificate (chepeast one) just work to non www urls. I've tested lot of setups to try to redirect the

https://www.domain.com to http://domain.com

but didn't work.

I want to get that Apache redirects https://www -> to https:// (without www).

But I don't know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just can't redirect to mentioned url. To redirect you need to have different url. 
For reference visit official apache docs -
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html